# Why do for in and for of loops not display a complex type properly?

Tags: javascript, object

I am Learning JavaScript and I would like to know why I am not able to print objects within for in and for of loops whereas I can if not inside a loop (see below):

```
let arr = [{abc: '123'}, {xyz: '321'}];
let obj = {obj1:{abc: '123'}, obj2:{xyz: '321'}};

for(let x of arr)
{
  console.log(`${x}`);
}
for(let x of arr)
{
  console.log(`${x}`);
}

console.log(arr[0]); // this works
console.log(obj.obj1); // this works
```

Could someone explain why this is please, it keeps printing [object object] and I have no idea why. I thought it should print the entire object and its contents

Comment: Try `console.log(x);`

Comment: Try console.table(x)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even contain a `for … in` loop?